# How to define a function to produce a Chernoff face?

Tags: graphics

How would I define a function to generate a Chernoff face in Mathematica without using the built in ChernoffFace[x]?

Comment: Do you mean `ChernoffFace` from [this package](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/making-chernoff-faces-for-data-visualization/)?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a manipulate that implements a display of a face controllable with the sliders on the left. Move/shift the eyes with the mouse.

```
Manipulate[eyeMat = {{1/(eyeRadius - pupilRadius/2), 0}, {0, 
    1/(0.15 + eyes - pupilRadius/2)}}; 
 If[Norm[eyeMat.(pup - eyeCenter[[left]])] < 1, 
  pupNow = pup - eyeCenter[[left]];]; 
 If[Norm[eyeMat.(pup - eyeCenter[[right]])] < 1, 
  pupNow = pup - eyeCenter[[right]];]; 
 Graphics[{face, eye[left, eyes], eye[right, eyes], Blue, 
   pupil[left, pupNow, eyes], pupil[right, pupNow, eyes], Black, 
   browDraw[left, brows, eyes], browDraw[right, brows, eyes], 
   Inset[mouthDraw[mouth], {0, -0.5}]}, ImageSize -> {400, 450}],
 {{brows, {-Pi/20, 0}}, {-0.6, 0}, {0.6, 0.15}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left},
 {{eyes, 0}, -0.07, 0.07, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  ControlType -> VerticalSlider},
 {{mouth, 0.15}, -0.401, 0.4, 0.01, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  ControlType -> VerticalSlider},
 {{pup, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}, 
 Initialization :> (face = Circle[{0, 0}, {1, 1.2}]; pupNow = {0, 0}; 
   left = 1; right = 2;
   eyeRadius = 0.18; eyeCenter = {{-0.4, 0.15}, {0.4, 0.15}}; 
   pupilRadius = 0.09;
   browUp = 0.25; browW = 0.2; browAng = Pi/20;
   eye[side_, eccen_] := {Black, 
     Circle[eyeCenter[[side]], {eyeRadius + 0.05, eyeRadius + eccen}]};
   pupil[side_, pup_, eccen_] := 
     {Disk[eyeCenter[[side]] + pup + {0, pup[[2]] eccen}, 
      pupilRadius + Max[0, eccen/3]], Black, 
     Disk[eyeCenter[[side]] + pup + {0, pup[[2]] eccen}, 0.03]};
   browDraw[side_, {browAng_, browLift_}, eccen_] := 
    Rotate[{Thickness[0.01], 
      Line[{{eyeCenter[[side]] + {-browW, browLift + browUp + 0.5 eccen}, 
         eyeCenter[[side]] + {browW, browLift + browUp + 0.5 eccen}}}]}, 
          2 (side - 1.5) browAng];
   mouthDraw[s_] := ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], -s Sin[u]}, {u, Pi/6, Pi - Pi/6}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}, PlotRange -> All];)]
```

[image]

[image]